# why is the output 1 in this case and when i am doing t-p then its giving me -1

Tags: c, pointers

As you can see it is giving me 1 but why?
When i do t-p then it gives me -1 . Why ?

```
int f=4, o=8;
int *p, *t;
p = &f;
t = &o;

printf("Difference between the two pointer is %d\n",p-t);
```

Comment: Pointer arithmetic between unrelated pointers make no sense. For it to make sense you need pointers to the same "array" (the pointers must be *related*).

Comment: For such questions you should alway also add what you would expect instead and why. Without that, we cannot see what you missed. Did you miss that you are doing pointer arithmetics? Did you expect compile error because you do arithmetics with unrelated addresses?

Answer (score 1):

`p-t` is not well-defined behavior. You cannot do pointer arithmetic unless the pointers point at the same array. Any kind of result is possible.

Furthermore the result of subtracting two pointers is a large integer type called `ptrdiff_t`. To print that one with `printf` you need to use `%tu`.

Although it is quite possible that the two variables are allocated adjacently in memory with 1 `sizeof(int)` bytes in between. Do this instead:

```
#include <stdint.h>
printf("%llu\n", (uintptr_t)p);
printf("%llu\n", (uintptr_t)t);
```

On a gcc x86 Linux PC I get:

```
140720377482824
140720377482828
```

So the result `-1` or `1` aren't very strange despite invoking undefined behavior.